# System.setOut() equivalent for PrintWriter

Tags: java, printwriter

How to set a overridden printwriter class as a default printwriter class. whenever i create a printwriter object, the object created should be the object of the overridden printwriter class. Like setting system.setOut(), is there any function available to set printwriter too.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of what you're trying to achieve? It would make the question easier to understand

Comment: I agree with that. As your idea doesn't work - if you want more than "this doesn't work" try giving a small example. Your other comment about stack trace elements is also about the "how to solve"... Tell us about the why you need to do this?!

Comment: I need to protect that data from being hacked. If hacked and a hacker access it, he might be getting only "" and not the data he expects. There is a class and it has a member s. S is private and I'm getting it through the public function. Whenever the sources like system.out.println or printwriter or httpservletresponse's writer try to access it, I should return "" instead of s. Whenever some other function inside the package access it, it should return s. This is what I'm trying to do. Not intrested in encrypting and using stacktraceelement to identify which method called this function.

Comment: Have already overriden the PrintStream inside that class and whenever anything tries to write some value to system.out, I checked whether it is s or not. If its s I printed "" using super.println("") else super.println(s) inside the overridden class. Set system.setout(overridenprintstream(system.out)). Now whatever data is going to get printed in system.out will be screened as it comes through the overriden PrintStream. For console this is ok and working. But doesn't know how to do the same with servlet. Struck at doing the same.for servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. In your example a very specific object is "replaced". Only System.out behaves differently. No other stream is affected by that call.

In other words: there is no way to change of what a call like *new X()* will do. If you want something other than an X object - you have to call *new Y()* for example.

Comment: I have to get writer from the servlet response. So whenever i try to write a specific string into this writer object, that string should be set to empty string. so if i write "sss" for example, it has to write "" to the writer get from reponse of the servlet. Is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: No chance. And also : wrong approach. If the writer should write nothing - then write nothing to it!

Comment: Yes of course. But the requirement goes like that. Scratching the head...have tried StackTraceElement but it is not allowed to use. So certainly have to find out a way which should return "" for that particular member if a function which can be of potential to expose it to the outside world access it. As of now, I know StackTraceElement is the only way. But I can't use it too. If you find out any cool stuff to achieve this, do share it, thanks in advance!